# Get Score for Single Entry ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

So, I have a basic elasticsearch index that consists of 3 elements

- id
- url
- content (text content)

I know how to write a query against elasticsearch to rank the documents, but what if I wanted to know just how 1 particular URL did on that query. For example, let's say http://www.google.com which had an ID of 2394823 was in the index and I wanted to know it's score for the query "search engine"

Is this possible in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a filtered query, looking at "search engine" in the content but filtering on the url value:

```
POST myindex/_search
{
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match": { "content": "search engine" }
         },
         "filter": {
             "term": { "url": { "http://www.google.com" }}
         }
     }
}
```

The only result should be the an element corresponding to google. From the response JSON, extract the score and you are done.

Comment: It should be noted that scores are normalized based on the search context -- e.g. the other documents that are being ranked.  If you only search for a single document, the score will be very different from the same document that is situated in the middle of a "regular" search for many docs. Single-doc scores are largely useless for that reason.